# Add Graphviz support to Markdown

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, graphs

### The Request

This is a request to add [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) ([DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)) support to [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). This will allow us to easily embed **editable** and **indexable** graphs in questions and answers. I imagine it will be particularly useful for [the theoretical CS site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8766/theoretical-computer-science) and for Stack Overflow itself, but I think any site of the many we have in SE-2.0 and the original trilogy can enjoy graph support.

I get a feeling this is going to get a very low priority, but perhaps the implementation is simple and more people than I expect will want this.

Finally, [here's what seems to be a proof of concept for embedding Graphviz in Python's Markdown implementation](http://lethain.com/entry/2010/jan/16/a-python-markdown-extension-for-embedding-graphviz/).

### Usage Example

Example of what I mean - using the following (proposed) Markdown,

```
<dot>
digraph {
    a -> b -> c;
    b -> d;
}
</dot>
```

Will embed the image:

[image: graphviz graph]

Generating the image can be as simple as giving that text as input to a server-installed copy of Graphviz and asking it to generate an image in return. The final result is just an image, so I don't see any potential abuse or security problem here.

**EDIT:** [a server-oriented module for generating diagrams, called WebDot, is also available directly from Graphviz's website.](http://www.graphviz.org/webdot/)

### Use Cases

There are currently over a hundred questions tagged [graphviz](/questions/tagged/graphviz) on Stack Overflow, I'm guessing many of them would enjoy that feature, though obviously this isn't the use-case I am thinking about.

I've used Graphviz myself in two different posts I've made, but if anyone else knows of other posts that could have used it, feel free to add these examples here. My posts:

- [Examples of Java APIs that demand an action sequence](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21480/examples-of-java-apis-that-demand-an-action-sequence)
- [Is there a chart showing all unit upgrade paths in Civilization 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/upgrade-paths-for-units-in-civilization-5/8102#8102) (it no longer uses Graphviz though, but check out the revision history)
- [How can I get a graphical representation of my dependencies with Spring.NET IoC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446068/how-can-i-get-a-graphical-representation-of-my-dependencies-with-spring-net-ioc/7455178#7455178)

Comment: I think .svg should be sufficient for this purpose; see edited answer below.

Comment: @Jeff SVGs are a lot harder to produce and edit than just writing a little text and immediately producing useful graphs. Text in SVGs is indexable, though, so that aspect is certainly addressed by your answer.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I totally agree with Oak

Comment: Inline Graphviz code could render to SVG and thereby be indexable.

Comment: Totally agree with Oak, inline DOT is that easy while one had to start an external application like Inkscape in order to produce a complex SVG markup.

Comment: SVG doesn't do graph layout. I use dot a lot.

Comment: The point of having dot support: 1) dot can do the layout 2) no special editor needed. *I would still love to see this.*

Comment: There is a [javascript graphviz renderer here](http://mdaines.github.io/viz.js/). Even without SE support one could write a bookmarklet/scriplet to find `<dot>...</dot>` strings, and replace them inline with client-side-rendered SVGs. But, of-course, SE built-in support for (even a subset of) `graphviz` in questions and answers would be great. I know, i'd use it.

Comment: Why can't we take this one step further? Can we have a graphic editor like gliffy? It would be much easier to add a simple graph to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please. Also, [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) support for basic animations and illustrations is incredibly useful. For example, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Pythagorean.svg

as a `.png`:

[image: png]

as a `.svg`:

[image: svg]

as an animated `.svg`:

http://www.bogotobogo.com/svg_source/Pythagorean.svg

(this also works inline but it has odd sizing, so removed)

Comment: as you can see from my edit, this already works, at least in Chrome...

Comment: @JeffAtwood What is meant by "odd sizing"? It stays the same size while animated. I'd let it be there, animated.