# Trying to insert a large animated GIF fails with a less-than-helpful message

Tags: support, images

When I try to insert/upload a large animated GIF into a post, I get the following error:

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

If I try to upload the same image directly to imgur, I get a message telling me that animated GIFs must be less than 2MB.  If that's the restriction that's causing the failure when I try to insert it, then the message I'm being shown is neither accurate nor helpful.

Comment: Is your large animated GIF any more helpful than this error you're encountering?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: [I tend to think so, as it's technical art](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155383/is-r-2-cos-theta-a-one-petal-polar-function/155466#155466), but I suppose I could replace it with a link instead.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o

Comment: <GLaDOS voice> Well... you passed the test.

Comment: @animuson: Ah, yeah, I hit that problem, too, but I didn't realize it was related.

Answer (score 6):

Um, this is a *FIFTEEN MEGABYTE* animated GIF. That's... insane.

I can't even load it into my GIF optimization software.

You might consider other representations, I believe .svg files support animation and are certainly supported on modern browsers. See: [Add Graphviz support to Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70933/add-graphviz-support-to-markdown)

Comment: If I export the same animation from Mathematica to SVG, I get a 40+MB file that doesn't render in Chrome (it looks vaguely like the first two frames, no animation, but has other issues).  Also, I'm not saying you should support large image uploads; I'm just saying that the error messages when rejecting large images are misleading or wrong.

Comment: can you at least render it down as a 16 color animated GIF? That would help a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can, [but I'll try to find out](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6561/7).

Comment: @Isaac using `gifsicle --optimize=3 --colors=16 < enormous.gif > smaller.gif` I get an output of 8mb versus 15mb with no appreciable loss in quality (the image is nearly monochrome to start with, so 16 colors is plenty good to represent the colors in it). However, I think you need to resize the image (920w is a bit large) and/or reduce the framerate and/or reduce the duration to get it under 2mb.

Comment: @isaac also of note, the image is being resized *anyway* by Stack Exchange to 630px (the maximum and standard post width) so any additional resolution is lost.

Comment: @isaac if nothing else, I strongly recommend updating to the 16 color version of your animation, since it's a 50% size reduction.