# Recommended way(s) to share video on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, videos

YouTube is a quick and easy way to share a video, but it

1. blocks content in some areas ([example](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/48340/whats-the-highest-percentage-of-output-any-country-spent-on-its-military?noredirect=1#comment77941_48340)),
2. requires account creation in order to upload video.

Is there any recommended way(s) to share videos in a way that *does not*:

- stop users viewing it according to their location, and
- require account creation

I particularly appreciate Pastebin, and Imgur for being extremely simple and reliable ways of sharing text and images respectively. But I cannot find an equivalent for video.

Comment: imgur accepts GIFS (though [not if they're too big](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135047/trying-to-insert-a-large-animated-gif-fails-with-a-less-than-helpful-message))

Comment: What would you want to share in a video that can't be shared in a GIF?

Comment: @Mast It's about selecting the right tool for the job. Animated GIFs are awesome because they can be very light weight and auto play. Videos can be much richer though (with audio), can be made to **not** autoplay (which can itself be important), and are supported by many common video editing softwares that people are familiar with. See the example in the question. Conversion into an animated GIF is possible, sure, but it adds nothing, yet removes a lot. So it's not about one being better than the other, but simply about selecting the right tool for the job.

Comment: The bandwith of a video is horrendously larger than that of text or a small GIF. I'm not sure the benefits would outweigh the cost.

Comment: @Mast Regarding bandwidth, consider that with an animated GIF, the user downloads the *whole* GIF when the page loads (whether they like it or not). With video, the user *opts-in* to the download of that content (by clicking play). In this way, video could actually be *more* efficient in certain cases. Ultimately although the two mediums overlap they are sufficiently different to warrant judicious use of either one depending on the circumstances. Neither is optimal over the other across *all* circumstances, content, audiences etc.